# In Xamarin.Forms when generating a AppPackage for uwp . Is there a way to convert it to .exe or something like click to install

Tags: uwp, xamarin.uwp

I am making a project in Xamarin and the UWP app creates a folder that I have to zip and send it to the client, in that folder is the appx file and a PowerShell file, then right-click on the PowerShell file and then it installs. Is there something to convert it to .exe or something like click to install for local distribution?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there something to convert it to .exe or something like click to install for local distribution?

Currently, there is no such tool could package uwp project as exe file, for uwp project, you could use Visual Studio to package. if you set `Generate apps bundle` never, it will make a appx file that could install directly.

And please note before install the appx, you need install the package certificate. For more detail please refer [Package a desktop or UWP app in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/package/packaging-uwp-apps).